# How to specify table stripe colors for knitr::kable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

How was this person able to make the tables shown in [this link](http://blogs.reed.edu/ed-tech/2015/10/creating-nice-tables-using-r-markdown/)? It doesn't look like they were passing any arguments to kable.

Here is the example:

[image]

Comment: `kable` just returns the structure; the color is added by CSS in the RMarkdown template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The styles of kable tables are controlled by CSS file. `tbody` can be used to change the colour of the content of the table, with `thead` able to change the header.

As shown by Lee S, you can create an external CSS file. However, you can also include the CSS directly within the R Markdown file, as markdown accepts raw HTML and passes it through unaltered. [See here for some more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022558/r-markdown-how-to-change-style-with-internal-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Here is a full reproducible example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

# Test Project

<style>
   tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F7FBFF;
  }
</style>


```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5])
```
````

[image]

> [This guide](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/) provides a good explanation of the table elements which can be controlled by CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Download the RMD file http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/software/R/blogposts/tables_blogpost.Rmd

Change beginning of RMD file to this:

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
    css: mystyles.css
---
```

Create a css file called mystyles.css with following contents:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #F7FBFF;
}
```

Save to the same location as your RMD file.